# v.stream.order extension does not install in GRASS 8.2

Tags: grass-gis, stream-order, add-ons

I'm trying to install the v.stream.order extension for GRASS 8.2 from here:

https://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass82/addons/grass-8.2.0/v.stream.order.zip

But inspecting the zip file, it seems to be incomplete, with no .html document or .bat/exe file.

When installing through the GRASS Gui, I get this warning, and an error.

> WARNING: No metadata available for module 'v.stream.order': Unable to fetch interface description for command '<v.stream.order>'.
>
> Details: Cannot find the executable v.stream.order
>
> ERROR: Unable to read manual page: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\... \AppData\Roaming\GRASS8\addons\docs\html\v.stream.order.html'

I'm using Windows 10 Business and plan to use the extension through the rgrass package.

Are errors on compiling extensions documented?  Or is there a way of compiling an extension for windows? With some instructions for dummies :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the addon log file at
https://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass82/addons/grass-8.2.0/logs/

--> vector/v.stream.order   FAILED  [log](https://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass82/addons/grass-8.2.0/logs/v.stream.order.log)

There is a ctypes problem:

```
  File "C:\msys64\usr\src\grass820\dist.x86_64-w64-mingw32\etc\python\grass\lib\ctypes_loader.py", line 105, in __call__
    raise ImportError("Could not load %s." % libname)
ImportError: Could not load grass_vector.8.2.
```

I have opened an upstream ticket:
https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/issues/771

Comment: I have used a workaround of installing GRASS 7.8 and using the v.stream.order extension from this version which seems to be the last working windows precompiled version. (https://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass78/x86_64/addons/grass-7.8.7/v.stream.order.zip)